# TypeError: string indices must be integers after json.loads()

Tags: python, json

I have the following string:

```
'"{\\"values\\": [3.304000000004, 3.010000000002, 5.8220000000063]}"'
```

I need to convert it into JSON. If I do:

```
parsed = json.loads(data)
parsed["values"]
```

...then I get the following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Your JSON appears to be double encoded…?! I.e., your JSON does not contain an object, it instead contains a string which contains an object.

Comment: @deceze: yes, sorry for a typo. Of course, it's `parsed`. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: here `data` is `string` not `dict`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments section, your data seem to be double encoded (a string of string of dict of some-sort).

Try parsing the string twice like this

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: data = '"{\\"values\\": [3.304000000004, 3.010000000002, 5.8220000000063]}"'

In [3]: parsed = json.loads(json.loads(data))

In [4]: parsed['values']
Out[4]: [3.304000000004, 3.010000000002, 5.8220000000063]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input string is not representing a JSON object: it's *A JSON formatted string of a JSON formatted string* as @deceze says.

```
'"{\\"values\\": [3.304000000004, 3.010000000002, 5.8220000000063]}"'
```

This is a just string.

It should be like this:

```
'{"values": [3.304000000004, 3.010000000002, 5.8220000000063]}'
```

Comment: Well, it *is* a JSON formatted string. A JSON formatted string of a JSON formatted string.